# любой запрос, отличный от корневого, возвращает ошибку 404

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

В своем проекте использую *web.py*. Удалось на 90% настроить связку *nginx+uwsgi+webpy*, сервер отдает статику и загружает главную страницу.

Проблема в том, что *nginx* не видит моих роутов. То есть, любой запрос, отличный от корневого, оканчивается *404 Not Found*

Файл `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` не трогал вообще.

Файл `/etc/nginx/site-avalable/default` выглядит следующим образом:

```
server {
        #listen 80;
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass 174.138.49.145:3031;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }
```

*Uwsgi* настроен и отдает главную страницу. Других конфигов не создавал. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Comment: А зачем вам `try_files` вообще? У вас статика лежит не в отдельном каталоге?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> любой запрос отличный от корневого оканчивается 404 Not Found

вы именно так и указали [директивой](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

расшифровка:

1. проверить наличие файла, совпадающего с полученным `uri`
2. если нет, проверить наличие каталога, совпадающего с полученным `uri`
3. если нет, вернуть http-ошибку номер 404

---

уберите или закомментируйте эту строку — и эти проверки не будут производиться (они вам в описанной вами ситуации и ни к чему).

Comment: спасибо большое!